# Dynamically create a Windows Account on EC2

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, vnc

I am looking to test a HTML5 VNC viewer with EC2. However, I would like to be able to create a separate Windows account every time I test with the VNC viewer. I'd also like to restrict the VNC session to use only one application.

Any ideas on what the best approach for this problem would be?

Thanks!